# Why my code is not working, not any homework

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to do a coding problem from 3 days from a website called Codechef, my code compiles, executes and even give correct results but the time limit for the question is 1 sec, my code is taking approx 1.01 sec , can you please tell where can I squeeze my code so that my code can execute within 1 sec. The question is :-

The question is about finding n-th smallest palindrome number, say n=9, then another k-th smallest palindrome number, say k=13, then I have to something like this :- [(nth)^(nth+1)]*[(nth)^(nth+2)] *.......*[(nth) ^(kth)], where nth+1 refers to 10th smallest palindrome number, nth+2 refers to 11th smallest palindrome number and so on

```
#include <stdio.h>

int chefora(int num){
  int real,t,sum=0,count=0;
  real=num;
  while(num!=0){
     t=num%10;
     sum=sum*10+t;
     num/=10;
     count++;
      }
  if(sum==real && count%2!=0)
  return real;
  else
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--){
        int arr[5001]={0},p;
        long long int product=1;
        int j=0,big=1000000007;
        int L,R,sum2=0;
        scanf("%d %d",&L,&R);
        int n;
        for(n=1;j<R;n++){    
            p=chefora(n);
            if(p==n)
               arr[j++]=n;
        }
        for(j=L+1;j<=R;j++)
            sum2+=arr[j-1];
            for(j=1;j<=sum2;j++)
                product=(product*arr[L-1])%big;
                printf("%lld",product);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: The question is about finding n-th smallest palindrome number , say n=9 , then another k-th smallest palindrome number, say k=12 , then I have to something like this :- [(nth)^(nth+1)]*[(nth)^(nth+2)] *.......*[(nth) ^(kth)] , where  nth+1 refers to 10th smallest palindrome number , nth+2 refers to 11th smallest palindrome number

Comment: Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I don't think it fits code review, because the code has a clearly stated problem.

Comment: The indentation of the code leads me to believe that you come from a python background. Your `for` loops are not working the way you probably think they are. If you _really_ mean them to do what they are doing now, please indent your code properly (consistently).

Comment: just 0.01 seconds slow? Fire it off a few times, it's bound to drop below 1 second one of the iterations.

Comment: do you have to `printf`? That's slow

Comment: @bereal - I see code in Code Review often where the poster asks for review to focus on such attributes as _execution speed_ or _better memory performance_.  These are clearly defined problems, or constraints or design parameters or ... (pick one)   Its all just semantics.  If this code works (as OP states it does:  _"my code compiles ,executes and even give correct results but the time limit for the question is 1 sec , my code is taking approx 1.01 sec"_) it sounds like a good fit for Code Review.

Comment: You meant that printf is making the code slow ? @yano

Comment: @Prince Do you really mean to run this loop: `for(j=1;j<=sum2;j++) product=(product*arr[L-1])%big;` and after the loop is finished `printf("%lld",product);` ? The same goes for the "outer" loop: `for(j=L+1;j<=R;j++) sum2+=arr[j-1];` will finish before you start with the next loop. Is that how you want it?

Comment: It's something extra, and in general `printf` is slow. If you're going for speed, get rid of it if you don't need it. Have you compiled with optimizations cranked up?

Comment: @Prince - anytime you write out to a file, or stream to `stdio` (which is essentially a file.) it is very time consuming.

Comment: @yano He's running this on a code competition site, he's not compiling it himself, I doubt he controls the optimization settings. And how will it produce output without `printf()`?

Comment: @Barmar return value? file output? I'm not familiar with competition sites, so I prefaced with _if_ it's not needed.

Comment: @yano Competition sites general work in one of 2 ways: They require you to define a function with a specific name that returns a value, or they require you to write a complete program that writes to stdout. Since he's writing a main function, it looks like the latter (which I think is most common, since it more language agnostic).

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relatively slow iterative method for creating palindromes. Instead of testing if every number is a palindrome, we can just generate them using the facts that we know about palindromes.

Perhaps something like:

```
int palindromes[5001] = {};
int p = 0;

// 1 digit palindromes
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  palindromes[p++] = i;

// 2 digit palindromes
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  palindromes[p++] = i*10 + i;

// 3 digit palindromes
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    palindromes[p++] = i*100 + j*10 + i;

// 4 digit palindromes
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    palindromes[p++] = i*1000 + j*100 + j*10 + i;

// 5 digit palindromes
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k<10; k++)
      palindromes[p++] = i*10000 + j*1000 + k*100 + j*10 + i;

// and so on.
```

Comment: Not bad.  Perhaps rather than a new `for()` tree per width, a recursive solution?  Or lets leave that to OP.

Comment: It's also useful to calculate how many palindromes each loop produces. If you only need the 12th palindrome, you only have to generate 1 and 2 digit palindromes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: While a recursive method would probably be nicer here, it would probably make it far less readable.

Comment: @Barmar: If we're truly worried about performance, it might be a good idea to statically generate this array and not build it at runtime.

Comment: I have used this way but still no change , time limit is exceeded for .01 sec , I have also used Barmar's say but still time limit is exceeded for .01 sec

Comment: @Prince: Would you mind sharing a link to the codechef site?

Comment: Yep,  here it is - https://www.codechef.com/JULY21C/problems/CHEFORA